# Why is the shield hero not venerated?

Tags: the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

I'm watching season 1 of Tate no yuusha no nariagari. It seems the shield hero was hated before he arrived, not after the incident with the princess, because there is a church which venerates the other 3 heroes but not the shield one.

Why is the shield hero not venerated?

Answer (score 0):

Because King Merlomarc has quarreled with a past hero of the shield

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain when this is stated in the series?

Comment: That is just part of the reason